# Why does the viewer uses developer-dev.api.autodesk.com instead of the developer.api.autodesk.com resulting in invalid tokens?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

The viewer v7 uses `https://developer-dev.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest` instead of `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest` which seems to prevent the viewer from getting the manifest data. The developer-dev host answers with:

```
{
    "developerMessage": "The token has expired or is invalid",
    "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
    "errorCode": "AUTH-006"
}
```

The same token works for the developer host just fine.

Does anyone know why the token only works for the developer host or why the viewer uses the developer-dev host instead of the developer host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Forge Viewer definitely does **not** connect to `https://developer-dev.api.autodesk.com` by default. For example, this basic Forge app is using viewer version 7.*: https://forge-basic-app.herokuapp.com, and it only communicates with `https://developer.api.autodesk.com`.

Are you perhaps using any custom settings when using the `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer` or when instantiating the actual viewer object?

Comment: Thank you! I set the `env` option to AutodeskDevelopment instead of AutodeskProduction. This resolved my problem!